# Magento trigger observer with custom orderstatus

Tags: magento, observers

I'm creating a Magento module and I want the Observer to trigger when my custom orderstatus is chosen.

Practical situation:
People select: 'Payment Received' the `//DO STUFF` in the Observer is triggered.

This ain't working, so what is wrong here? (the status shows up correctly though) :-(

**config.xml:**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <MOD_PaidStatus>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </MOD_PaidStatus>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <sales>
            <order>
                <statuses>
                    <payment_received translate="label"><label>Payment Received</label></payment_received>
                </statuses>
                <states>
                    <processing translate="label">
                        <label>Processing</label>
                        <statuses>
                            <processing default="1"/>
                            <payment_received default="2" />
                        </statuses>
                        <visible_on_front/>
                    </processing>
                    <pending translate="label">
                        <label>Pending</label>
                        <statuses>
                            <pending default="1"/>
                            <payment_received default="2" />
                        </statuses>
                        <visible_on_front/>
                    </pending>
                </states>                  
            </order>            
        </sales> 
        <events>
                <sales_order_resource_save_attribute_after>
                        <observers>
                                <PaidStatus>                                        
                                        <class>MOD_PaidStatus/observer</class>         
                                        <method>observeAttributeChange</method>
                                        <type>singleton</type>
                                </PaidStatus>
                        </observers>
                </sales_order_resource_save_attribute_after>
        </events>
    </global>
</config>
```

And my **Observer.php** looks like:

```
class MOD_PaidStatus_Model_Observer {

public function observeAttributeChange($observer){
    $attribute = $observer->getEvent()->getAttribute();
    if  ($attribute->getAttributeCode() == 'status') {
        mail('test@testcase.com', 'testcase', 'foo bar?');
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

In order to be able to execute some actions on changing the order's attribute "status" it is preferable to observe an event. In this case the event would be `sales_order_resource_save_attribute_after`. The observer function could be set up as follows:

```
class YourPackage_YourModule_Model_Observer {

public function observeAttributeChange($observer) 
{

    $attribute = $observer->getEvent()->getAttribute();

    if  ($attribute->getAttributeCode() == 'status') {
    // DO STUFF
    }
}
```

In your config.xml enter the necessary observer configuration

```
<global>
        <events>
                <sales_order_resource_save_attribute_after>
                        <observers>
                                <your_observer_node_name>                                        
                                        <class>yourpackage_yourmodule/observer</class>         
                                        <method>observeAttributeChange</method>
                                        <type>singleton</type>
                                </your_observer_node_name>
                        </observers>
                </sales_order_resource_save_attribute_after>
        </events>
</global>
```

Comment: thanks, I've updated the code in the question, but I'm not sure I understand. I still don't get an email at: test@testcase.com

Comment: Can you check if the function `observeAttributeChange($observer)` is called? (using a debugger or inserting a log call). If yes, is the attributeCode equal 'status'?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with rewriting or observer.

You do a kind of mix of these 2 concepts.

To use rewrite, do not name your file Observer, use something like **Order**.php :

```
class MOD_PaidStatus_Model_**Order** extends Mage_Sales_Model_Order
```

and in your config.xml, in the global node, add this :

```
<models>
    <sales>
         <rewrite>
             <order>MOD_PaidStatus_Model_Order</order>
         </rewrite>
    </sales>
</models>
```

If you want to go through an Observer, use the name Observer.php and the classname should be :

```
MOD_PaidStatus_Model_Observer
```

and it shouldn't extends anything.

The function is more like

```
public function myEventHandling($event)
{
    $order = $event->getOrder();
    $status = $order->getStatus();
    //DO YOUR STUFF here
}
```

But your should listen for a order_status_changed_after event that doesn't exist, so you add to trigger it too... Very big stuff if you're not a confirmed developer.

If you want something like this, you need an event node in your config.xml file to associate your Observer and its method to the event. Make some search about event handling in Magento

Regards,

Edit.: for observer and event way, look the previous post. But handling such a generic event is a very resource consuming way.

Comment: thanks for the answer, I've updated the post, but I still don't get an email and I can't see what's wrong here :-S